# VueJS | How to have different select values in a v-for list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make the formatting of the chess competition our local club is running dynamic, and I use VueJS for it. The idea is that the results submitted to the given pairings automatically update the standings. The whole pairing list is loaded via a v-for list. However, each updated result of a game appears in all the select menus like so:

[image]

The funny thing is that the values of just Player 1 & Player 2, Player 3 & Player 5 etc. *do* change according to which dropdown I set to 1-0, ½-½ of 0-1. I tried adding `:key="index"` or `:name="result"` to the select menu, `:selected="true"` to the null-option, but without any effect. I would love to change the select v-model name, but I use "result" to update the updateAfterGame method. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can make each row unique? It could very well be just a JavaScript issue, I am not sure.

**HTML**

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>white</th>
        <th>black</th>
        <th>result</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(game, index) in pairings">
        <td>{{game.white}}</td>
        <td>- {{game.black}}</td>
        <td><select v-model="result" @change="updateAfterGame(game.r_white, result, game.r_black, 1-result)">
              <option value="">    *  </option>
              <option value="1"> 1 - 0</option>
              <option value=".5">½ - ½</option>
              <option value="0"> 0 - 1</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        pairings: [
          {white: 'Player 1', r_white: 0, black: 'Player 2', r_black: 1},
          {white: 'Player 3', r_white: 2, black: 'Player 5', r_black: 4},`
        ]
      },
      methods: {
        updateAfterGame: function (no1, result1, no2, result2) {
          // changes the standings; irrelevant for the question
        }
      }
    }
```

Kind regards,

Bert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting the final result into the data array ? like this:

```
 pairings: [
        {
          white: "Player 1",
          r_white: 0,
          black: "Player 2",
          r_black: 1,
          finalResult: ""
        },
        {
          white: "Player 3",
          r_white: 2,
          black: "Player 5",
          r_black: 4,
          finalResult: ""
        }
      ]
```

And specify that in v-model like v-model="game.finalResult"

So it would be like  this:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>white</th>
        <th>black</th>
        <th>result</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(game, index) in pairings">
        <td>{{game.white}}</td>
        <td>- {{game.black}}</td>
        <td>
          <select
            v-model="game.finalResult"
            @change="updateAfterGame(game.r_white, game.finalResult, game.r_black, 1-game.finalResult)"
          >
            <option value>*</option>
            <option value="1">1 - 0</option>
            <option value=".5">½ - ½</option>
            <option value="0">0 - 1</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data: function() {
    return {
      pairings: [
        {
          white: "Player 1",
          r_white: 0,
          black: "Player 2",
          r_black: 1,
          finalResult: ""
        },
        {
          white: "Player 3",
          r_white: 2,
          black: "Player 5",
          r_black: 4,
          finalResult: ""
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateAfterGame: function(no1, result1, no2, result2) {
      // changes the standings; irrelevant for the question
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Oh how silly of me. I actually had a "result" in the array when it was all static. Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

if you save all game results in one variable it is obvious that all rows are going to be the same. In order to save each game result individually you should move your result into the pairings array like so

**Javascript**

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pairings: [
      {white: 'Player 1', r_white: 0, black: 'Player 2', r_black: 1, result: "0"},
      {white: 'Player 3', r_white: 2, black: 'Player 5', r_black: 4, result: "0"},`
    ]
  }
}
```

then you can bind your result like this

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>white</th>
    <th>black</th>
    <th>result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(game, index) in pairings" :key="index">
    <td>{{game.white}}</td>
    <td>- {{game.black}}</td>
    <td><select v-model="game.result">
          <option value="">    *  </option>
          <option value="1"> 1 - 0</option>
          <option value=".5">½ - ½</option>
          <option value="0"> 0 - 1</option>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also you should always include the key attribute when implementing a v-for list, with this vue knows which rows it has to update

Comment: Oh how silly of me. I actually had a "result" in the array when it was all static. And a useful hint about the key attribute, even when it hacks about without it. Thank you for helping me out!